# Determining number of repeat measures needed to deal with measurement error through bootstrapping?

Tags: repeated-measures, bootstrap, measurement-error

I have a performance test with a high degree of inherent measurement error. I have some data from a pilot study where I took 30 repeat measures with a single device and I want to figure out how many repeat measures (hopefully less than 30!) will provide me with a reasonable estimate of the mean for an individual device.

I wrote a script in `R` to try to check convergence for various sample sizes. The general idea is, for each sample size from `n to N`

1. Pull a random sample (without replacement) of size `n` from the original sample of size `N`
2. Run a bootstrap parameter estimate on this sample using `B` resamples
3. Do it again `X` times
4. Average the `X` parameter estimates and check convergence (i.e. check standard deviation between measurements) to see how many samples I need.

**Is this a valid approach for trying to figure out how many repeat measures to include for each device in a performance test?**

I was planning to do `X=10,000` estimates for each sample size using `B=10,000` resamples each. **Does this sound like enough?**
Would `X=1,000` and `B=100,000` be better?  Not sure how to determine what is best.

I ran a test with `X=10,000` and `B=500` and it took a little under an hour, so I don't expect any problems resource-wise.